# R: NA/NaN/Inf in X error

Tags: r

I am trying to perform a negative binomial regression using R. When I am executing the following command:

```
 DV2.25112013.nb <- glm.nb(DV2.25112013~ Bcorp.Geographic.Proximity + Dirty.Industry +
                Clean.Industry + Bcorp.Industry.Density + State + Dirty.Region +
                Clean.Region + Bcorp.Geographic.Density + Founded.As.Bcorp + Centrality +
                Bcorp.Industry.Density.Squared + Bcorp.Geographic.Density.Squared +
                Regional.Institutionalization + Sales + Any.Best.In.Class +           
                Dirty.Region.Heterogeneity + Clean.Region.Heterogeneity + 
                Ind.Dirty.Heterogeneity+Ind.Clean.Heterogeneity + Industry, 
                data = analysis25112013DF6)
```

R gives the following error:

```
Error in glm.fitter(x = X, y = Y, w = w, etastart = eta, offset = offset,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'
In addition: Warning message:
step size truncated due to divergence
```

I do not understand this error since my data matrix does not contain any NA/NaN/Inf values...how can I fix this?

thank you,

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52527/unable-to-fit-negative-binomial-regression-in-r-attempting-to-replicate-publish).

Comment: Great catch by @Stat . Otherwise, however, this is (1) really a StackOverflow rather than a CrossValidated question (i.e. programming rather than statistics), and (2) very hard to answer without a http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 reproducible example unless someone happens to guess right ...

Comment: Agree w/ other comments (and the referenced question): trying to do an iterative convergence w/ that many independent variables is uuuugly.

Answer (score 2):

<del>I think the most likely cause of this error are negative values or zeros in the data, since the default link in glm.nb is 'log'. It would be easy enough to test by changing `link="identity"`.</del>   I also think you need to try smaller models .... maybe a quarter of those variables to start. That also lets you add related variables as bundles since it looks from the names that you have possibly severe potential for collinearity with categorical variables.

We really need a data description. I wondered about `Dirty.Industry + Clean.Industry`. That is the sort of dichotomy that is better handled with a factor variable that has those levels. That prevents the collinearity if Clean = not-Dirty. Perhaps similarly with your "Heterogeneity" variables. (I'm not convinced that @BenBolker's comment is correct. I think it very possible that you first need statistical consultation before address coding issues.)

```
require(MASS)
data(quine)  # following example in ?glm.nb page

> quine$Days[1] <- -2

> quine.nb1 <- glm.nb(Days ~ Sex/(Age + Eth*Lrn), data = quine, link = "identity")
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  negative values not allowed for the 'Poisson' family

> quine$Days[1] <- 0
> quine.nb1 <- glm.nb(Days ~ Sex/(Age + Eth*Lrn), data = quine, link = "identity")
Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values
In addition: Warning message:
In log(y/mu) : NaNs produced
```

Comment: Note that a log link is fine for data that is 0.  With the link you're modeling the mean response - you aren't applying the link directly to the data itself.

Comment: I was thinking that the LHS input was part of the "the data".

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying.  In a negative binomial model with any link having a 0 as the response is not an issue.  You aren't actually taking the log of the response - you're saying that the log of the expected value has a linear form.

Comment: Agree with @Dason, I think the first two sentences of your answer are wrong/misleading (you're fundamentally misunderstanding how link functions in GLMs work ...) I agree there might be collinearity problems/ this might be on the borderline between "your model isn't sufficiently well specified to fit" (=statistical problem) and "your model is sensible in principle but difficult to fit in practice" (=computational problem)

Comment: Still think we need better description of the data and resolution of statistical issues as the first priority. The errors generated by negative numbers or zeros do no match error offered by OP but are left in to offer concrete examples regarding last two comments.

Answer (score 2):

i have resolved this issue by putting in the control argument into the model assumptions with maxiter=10 or lower. the default is 50 iterations. perhaps it works for you with a little more iterations. just try