# The MASS::glm.nb package is returning an error for some datasets

Tags: r, glm

I am trying to fit a particular binomial glm to the following data.

```
testData <- structure(list(lb = c(0.102, 0.128, 0.161, 0.203, 0.256, 0.323, 
0.406, 0.512, 0.645, 0.813, 1.02, 1.29, 1.63, 2.05, 2.58, 3.25, 
4.1, 5.16, 6.5, 8.19, 10.3, 13, 16.4, 20.6, 26), TotalParticles = c(50612, 
20541, 18851, 8058, 5606, 4123, 1995, 1234, 677, 381, 202, 111, 
75, 42, 64, 118, 127, 83, 9, 2, 4, 7, 67, 8, 143), binsize = c(0.026, 
0.033, 0.042, 0.053, 0.067, 0.083, 0.106, 0.133, 0.168, 0.207, 
0.27, 0.34, 0.42, 0.53, 0.67, 0.85, 1.06, 1.34, 1.69, 2.11, 2.7, 
3.4, 4.2, 5.4, 6), vol = c(309.76, 309.76, 309.76, 309.76, 309.76, 
309.76, 309.76, 309.76, 309.76, 309.76, 309.76, 309.76, 309.76, 
309.76, 309.76, 309.76, 309.76, 309.76, 309.76, 309.76, 309.76, 
309.76, 309.76, 309.76, 309.76)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -25L))
```

I have no trouble fitting a poisson glm to the data.

```
fit_model <- function(df) glm(TotalParticles ~ log(lb), offset = log(binsize * vol), data = df, family = "poisson")
summary(fit_model(testData))
```

> ```
> Call:
> glm(formula = TotalParticles ~ log(lb), family = "poisson", data = df, 
>     offset = log(binsize * vol))
>
> Deviance Residuals: 
>     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
> -42.592   -3.216    1.539   14.514   40.162  
>
> Coefficients:
>              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
> (Intercept)  1.276493   0.013243   96.39   <2e-16 ***
> log(lb)     -3.216526   0.006667 -482.44   <2e-16 ***
> ---
> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
> (Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)
>
>     Null deviance: 1152482.7  on 24  degrees of freedom
> Residual deviance:    6489.9  on 23  degrees of freedom
> AIC: 6677.5
>
> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
> ```

I can also fit a quasipoisson model. Which gives me exactly the same coefficients, though slightly /higher/ p-values.

```
fit_quasi <- function(df) glm(TotalParticles ~ log(lb), offset = log(binsize * vol), data = df, family = "quasipoisson")
summary(fit_quasi(testData))
```

> ```
> Call:
> glm(formula = TotalParticles ~ log(lb), family = "quasipoisson", 
>     data = df, offset = log(binsize * vol))
>
> Deviance Residuals: 
>     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
> -42.592   -3.216    1.539   14.514   40.162  
>
> Coefficients:
>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
> (Intercept)   1.2765     0.9662   1.321    0.199    
> log(lb)      -3.2165     0.4864  -6.613 9.54e-07 ***
> ---
> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
> (Dispersion parameter for quasipoisson family taken to be 5322.668)
>
>     Null deviance: 1152482.7  on 24  degrees of freedom
> Residual deviance:    6489.9  on 23  degrees of freedom
> AIC: NA
>
> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
> ```

However, when I try to fit a negative binomial model, I get this cryptic error message

```
fit_nb = function(df) MASS::glm.nb(TotalParticles ~ log(lb) + offset(log(vol * binsize)), data = df)
fit_nb(testData)
```

> Error in glm.fitter(x = X, y = Y, w = w, etastart = eta, offset =
> offset, : NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'

```
traceback()
```

> ```
> 3: glm.fitter(x = X, y = Y, w = w, etastart = eta, offset = offset, 
>        family = fam, control = list(maxit = control$maxit, epsilon = control$epsilon, 
>            trace = control$trace > 1), intercept = attr(Terms, "intercept") > 
>            0)
> 2: MASS::glm.nb(TotalParticles ~ log(lb) + offset(log(vol * binsize)), 
>        data = df) at #1
> 1: fit_nb(testData)
> ```

The problem seems related to the non-linear nature of the data. For instance, if I zero out the last five values, I can do the binomial regression, though I get a warning.

```
testDataWorks <- testData
testDataWorks[(nrow(testDataWorks)-4):nrow(testDataWorks),"TotalParticles"] <- 0
```

```
fit_nb(testDataWorks)
```

> ```
> glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
> Call:  MASS::glm.nb(formula = TotalParticles ~ log(lb) + offset(log(vol * 
>     binsize)), data = df, init.theta = 1.66759784, link = log)
>
> Coefficients:
> (Intercept)      log(lb)  
>       1.765       -2.892  
>
> Degrees of Freedom: 24 Total (i.e. Null);  23 Residual
> Null Deviance:        4954 
> Residual Deviance: 29.95  AIC: 315.8
> ```

Why exactly is my binomial regression failing? Is there a work-around that I can do to get it to run anyway? I get that these data aren't really particularly linear, but I would like to be able to run the model anyway for reasons (I have a bunch of similar data andthis mostly works for them).

I see that my problem is similar to this one [R: NA/NaN/Inf in X error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20814590/r-na-nan-inf-in-x-error) however, the consensus seemed to be that that user's model had way too many parameters, while in my case I have many fewer paramters to predict total particles.

This post https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52527/unable-to-fit-negative-binomial-regression-in-r-attempting-to-replicate-publish may also be relevant, though I'm not exactly sure how I would apply it in practice.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: work-around? I find that `mgcv::gam(..., family="nb")` is a bit more forgiving, but check plots of fit to see if sensible. Using this you could also model the non-linearity.

Comment: Great point. I tend to think of gams as requiring smooth coefficinets, but actually they don't, and gam does have "nb" as an option. Thanks. Thus `fit_nb2 <- function(df) gam(TotalParticles ~ log(lb), offset = log(binsize * vol), data = df, family = "nb")
summary(fit_nb2(testData))` seems to give me a reaonable output.